# find_element_by_partial_link_text ascii code issue

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

http://www.m2sys.com/.

When I click on CloudApper™ under Solutions I get an ascii code error.

I find the element using:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('CloudApper™')
```

How can I click the partial link?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the TM in superscript while searching for CloudApper™.

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('CloudApper')
```

There are two instances by  link text CloudApper™ in the target page. You can use this for finding the link  cloudApper located below solutions. **driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='mobile-advanced']//a[contains(@href,'cloudapper')]")**

Comment: I didn't visited the page earlier. You can use this for finding the link below cloudApper. **driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'CloudAapper')]")**

Answer (score 0):

CloudApper™ is a label, you have to click logo, use this xpath

```
//a[@href='http://www.m2sys.com/cloudapper-modularized-framework-enterprise-cloud-application/']
```

Comment: if needed the quotes style

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

first, you need to interact with the menu:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-15554").click();
```

then click on the actual element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'cloudapper-modularized-framework-enterprise-cloud-application')]").click();
```

Comment: It says element not visible